# `which` finds file, but `bash` doesn't

Tags: bash, pip, fabric

I installed [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/) via `pip`.

Got `pip` by:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Got fabric by:

```
sudo pip install fabric
```

(It failed when I tried w/out sudo, and warns me about a lack of files in docs or tests).

Now I get the following:

```
$ which fab
/usr/local/bin/fab
$
$ fab
bash: /usr/bin/fab: No such file or directory
```

Huh!? I thought `which` searched the `PATH` for the resolution that would be used by bash.  Am I misunderstanding something?  Is Fabric, Pip, or Bash to blame here?  How do I fix it?

I know for now I can run `/usr/local/bin/fab` or:

```
`which fab` deploy
```

But I want it to run correctly!

Comment: What does `type fab` say?

Comment: $ type fab
fab is /usr/local/bin/fab

Comment: So...how is understanding Bash ("A tool used primarily for programming") off topic here? I strongly disagree.

Comment: The problem here seems to be more with the aspects of bash affecting interactive use, not scripting.

Comment: Ok, that's very fair...I usually script things with relative paths, relying reasonably heavily on PATH working the way it does interactively...but that's reasonable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following will clear where bash *thinks* `fab` is located:

```
hash -d fab
```

Comment: Explain? I won't enter it w/out understanding it...

Comment: also "which hash" returns none

Comment: It updates the shell's hash of locations of commands. It's in `man bash`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks.  Here's what I get:$ `hash -d fab
bash: hash: fab: not found`

Comment: And yet that fixed it...Just realized it.  Sorry for not testing earlier!  Appreciate it.

Comment: Were you in a different shell invocation when you did that? Each new shell starts with a fresh cache.

Answer (score 1):

If `which fab` is in `/usr/*local*/bin`, but `/usr/bin/fab` can't be run, I would think of a broken symlink. Or `/usr/local/bin/fab` is a script that calls `/usr/bin/fab` (which doesn't exist).

Try `file /usr/local/bin/fab`.

Comment: file /usr/local/bin/fab
/usr/local/bin/fab: Python script, ASCII text executable

Comment: Check the first line(s) of the script; do they point to a non-existing `/usr/bin` executable?